# Add an enclosing circle to my UIButton

Tags: ios, uibutton, uikit

I have what I think is a simple question. I have a `UIButton` that is an image - that is, I've put a `UIImage` in the `imageView` attribute of the button.

Right now it looks like this:

[image]

I'd like to either give the heart a black border OR surround the heart with an enclosing `UIView` that is a black or dark gray circle.

I've tried setting the `borderColor` and `borderWidth` on the underlying layer of the `imageView` but the border it draws is around the "box" of the view, so it looks pretty ugly.

Is there a simple/easy way I can add a border to my image or maybe add a subview to the button so that an enclosing circle appears?

One thing that may be important to note: the heart starts off as being colored white, then when someone touches it, it turns red. I'm using this to implement a "favorites" feature. The way I'm toggling the color is with this code:

```
func setFavoriteState(_ isFavorite: Bool) {
  let favoriteColor : UIColor = isFavorite ? .red : .white
  favoriteButton.imageView?.tintColor = favoriteColor
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use different image for heart ?? I mean you can have two heart image , one with red circle in the background, one with black and while you click the heart change the image . This should work if you don't use animation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this is to have two separate images, one for the favorite state and one for the unfavorite state. You can then check the current image of your UIButton then change it to the other one once clicked  like the example below:

```
    @IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: Any) {

      if (yourButton.currentImage?.isEqual(UIImage(named: "favorite_icon")))! {
          yourButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "unfavorite_icon"), for: .normal)  
      } else {
        yourButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "favorite_icon"), for: .normal)
      }
    }
```

Comment: I don't know that it's the best way, but it definitely seems like the easiest way! I was sort of hoping to find a way to draw a border around the heart.

Comment: Hope the solution works for you, @bitops. Will you accept my answer?

Comment: I'll accept it because you were kind and wrote up an answer. I _was_ sorta hoping for some guidance around drawing but fair is fair.